# how to avoid "Compile Error: Can't find object or library"

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that runs through a list of several thousand workbooks and picks up data from each one.

I'm getting the following error when the script tries to open certain workbooks:

```
Compile Error: Can't find project or library
```

I thought that I could avoid this message, which I understand is a due to problem with references, by opening workbooks without macros or alerts this way:

```
dim bk as workbook
for each path in listOfWorkbookPaths
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.EnableEvents=false
 set bk=workbooks.open(path)
 Application.EnableEvents=true
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 collectData(bk)
next
```

But this doesn't work; I still get the compile error.  Is there any way to make sure this error doesn't pop up?

Comment: Could maybe try this approach using `AutomationSecurity`: http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/10/disabling-macros-in-workbook-excel-vba.html

Comment: What happens when you open those certain workbooks manually? Do you see an error?

Comment: I think the error lies in `collectData`. Anyway, you can solve this problem by opening VBEditor --> Tools-->References   to check for which reference is "MISSING"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `AutomationSecurity`settings:

```
Sub ImportFromExternalWorkbooks()
    Dim bk as Workbook
    Dim secAutomation As MsoAutomationSecurity

    secAutomation = Application.AutomationSecurity
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    For Each path in listOfWorkbookPaths
        Set bk=Workbooks.Open(path)
        collectData bk
    Next
    Application.AutomationSecurity = secAutomation 
End Sub
```